# How to add a breakline inside a cell with Excel4node module in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel4node

I need to insert a multiline cell with module [excel4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node), in documentation I didn't found anything about this.
I tried to insert the escape sequence `"\n"` but it didn't work. This is my code:

```
var xl = require('excel4node');
var wb = new xl.Workbook();
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

ws.cell(1, 1).string('first line \n second line');
```

And this is the result inside the cell:

```
first line \n second line
```

Somebody knows how it's possible to insert a multiline cell? Which char must I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My friendo

Have you tried this way?

```
ws.cell(1, 1).formula('="first line"&CHAR(10)&"second line"');
```

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered this problem some time ago.
I resolved with:

```
ws.cell(1, 1).formula('="first line"&CHAR(10)&"second line"');
```

Answer (score 4):

Helped a colleague yesterday who was having the same issue, after a while we came up with this solution.

```
ws.cell(1, 1).formula('="first line"&CHAR(10)&"second line"');
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this to insert breaklines

```
ws.cell(row, col).string('text to print \n another line').style({ alignment: { wrapText: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried alignment and it works

```
const style = ws.createStyle({
  alignment: {
    wrapText: true,
  },
})
ws.cell(4, 2).string('new\nline').style(style)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. I hope this could help. By this code, you can also format a specific line

```js
var complexstring = [
  'line1\n',
  {
    bold: true,
    size: 7,
    name: 'Arial',
    italics: true,
    value: 'line2'
  }
]
ws.cell(4, 2).string(complexstring)
```